# Hidden columns in Material-Table causing crash

Tags: javascript, material-table

I have three columns in my Material-Table which provide useful data but are not essential.  I want these columns hidden by default when the page is loaded, but give the user the option to un-hide them.  I have the `columnsButton` option set which allows me to manually select which columns I want hidden.  By default, no columns are hidden.

I have tried using `hidden: true` and `hiddenByColumnsButton: true`.  `hidden` just hides the column and the option to show it does not appear in the `columnsButton` list. `hiddenbyColumnsButton` does not hide the column and no effect the functionality of the list.  Using both of them at the same time in the same column results in the app crashing: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined`

This is my table and a two of my columns.  For the purpose of this question, I want to have `Title` hidden by default with the option to display it in the `columnsButton` list.

```
    const columns = [
        {
            title: <Typography className={classes.colHeader}>Intake ID</Typography>,
            field: "IntakeID",
            cellStyle: { minWidth: 118, maxWidth: 118 },
            // hidden: true,
        },
        {
            title: <Typography className={classes.colHeader}>Title</Typography>,
            field: "Title",
            cellStyle: { minWidth: 280, maxWidth: 280 },
            hidden: true,
            hiddenByColumnsButton: true,
        },
    ];

...
                <MTable
                    title="Table"
                    data={intakes.intakes}
                    columns={columns}
                    options={{
                        columnsButton: true,
                        pageSize: 10,
                        pageSizeOptions: [10, 15, 25, 50, 100],
                        paginationType: "stepped",
                        padding: "small",
                        filtering: true,
                />
```

Answer (score 0):

follow this https://codesandbox.io/s/material-table-with-hidden-columns-cndj4?file=/package.json:250-256

i downgraded the version to `1.57.2` and its working fine now